# Register blueprint in Python Flask unittest doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

I can confirm that my unittest and api was already working but after moving my stuff to a Blueprint, my unittest kept on failing while the api is still working. I'm stumped, looking for ideas.

Here are the codes in question:

```
# project/app/__init__.py

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request, jsonify, abort, Flask

from instance.config import app_config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)

    from app.api import api
    app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

    return app
```

Blueprint File

```
# project/app/api/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

from app.api import campaigns
```

Test File

```
# project/test_campaigns.py

import unittest
import json
from app import create_app, db
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from instance.config import app_config

class CampaignsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Campaigns Test Case"""

    def setUp(self):
        """Define test varibles and initialize app."""
        self.app = create_app(config_name="testing")
        self.client = self.app.test_client
        self.campaigns = {'name': 'Test Campaign'}

        #binds the app to the current context
        with self.app.app_context():
            # create all tables
            db.create_all()


    def test_create_campaign(self):
        """Test API can create campaign (POST Request)"""
        res = self.client().post('/api/campaigns/', data=self.campaigns)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
        self.assertIn('Test', str(res.data))

    ### REST OF TEST ####
```

API Route File. This is where I used the '/campaigns' route which will be prefixed by '/api'.

```
# project/app/api/campaigns.py

from app.api import api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request, jsonify, abort, Flask

import os

@api.route('/campaigns/', methods=['POST'])
def create_campaign():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        if name:
            campaign = Campaign(name=name)
            campaign.save()
            response = jsonify({
                'id': campaign.id,
                'name': campaign.name,
                'date_created': campaign.date_created
            })
            response.status_code = 201
            return response
```

All of my test results into a 404

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_create_campaign (__main__.CampaignsTestCase)
Test API can create campaign (POST Request)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_campaigns.py", line 25, in test_create_campaign
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
AssertionError: 404 != 201
```

Comment: Have you checked urls ?

Comment: Yes, @Kalanamith. As I've said, the APIs are working and the problem is only with running the unit test. I'm using the unittest package to do this, btw.

Comment: from your code, no code shows how '/campaigns' registered to '/api' blueprint, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Dominic try to print the self.client and the URL format I am pretty sure there's a mess up in url format used in Tests

Comment: @georgexsh, sorry I forgot to include that bit of code in the question.

Comment: @Kalanamith, you're absolutely right and there was just a mess up in url format :| Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @Dominic Cheers!